# How do I get source code into a column in Excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I paste source code into a column(column C) not into a cell(C1)?

```
Sub Tester()
Range("c1").Value = GetSource("https://www.yahoo.com/")
End Sub


Function GetSource(sURL As String) As String

Dim oXHTTP As Object

Set oXHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
oXHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
oXHTTP.send
GetSource = oXHTTP.responsetext
Set oXHTTP = Nothing

End Function
```

**Want this**
[image: want this]

**Not like this**
[image: [not like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do what you want you need a valid line separator, if yow know it you can try this code

```
Sub Tester()
s = GetSource("https://www.google.com/")
separator="?" '<<< to changed
arr = Split(s, separator)
For r = 0 To UBound(arr)
  Cells(r + 1, 1) = arr(r)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works but causes
run-time error'1004'
aplication-defined or object-defined error

Comment: which separator did you use?

Comment: hi, before i used "<", but now i am using chr(10) as separator and there is no problem now thank you very much again